# ASP.Net (3.5) MVC partial class for rule validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-classes

I have  2 projects. A data project, which contains my database and my Entity Framework model. I have table called 'User', and then have a generated EF class for user.

I am trying to add a partial class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Data
{
    public partial class user
    {

        public bool isValid
        {
            get {
                return (GetRuleViolations().Count()==0);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
        {
            yield break;
        }



        partialvoid OnValidate(ChangeAction action)
        {
            if (isValid)
                throw new ApplicationException("Rule violation prevents saving");
        }
    }

    public class RuleViolation
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

        public RuleViolation (string errorMessage)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

        public RuleViolation(string errorMessage, string propertyName)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            PropertyName = propertyName;
        }
    }
}
```

This is following the MVC 1.0 NerdDinner example. However, I am getting a design time error on the OnValidate method:

```
    partial void OnValidate(ChangeAction action)
    {
        if (isValid)
            throw new ApplicationException("Rule violation prevents saving");
    }
```

No definining declaration found for implimenting declaration of partial method 'void OnValidate(ChangeAction action)'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am still not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be another file containing the rest of the user class.

In this file you have to declare that there might be a partial method called OnValidate.

```
public partial class user
{
    partial void OnValidate(ChangeAction action);
}
```

Some detail:
A partial method needs to have a signature specified somewhere.  Once the signature has been defined then an optional implementation can be specified.  Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thanks. The original class file is generated, and marked as partial. However, it has no OnValidate method. The class/method, however, is generated when I create my Entity Framework model. I don't think I shopuld be modifying it, and adding a method, should I? I thought the idea was that my non-generated code would be in my custom partial class file, with the original (generated) class not being touched. Next time I generate the EF model, I will lose the changes.

Comment: The issue was, I was using the Entity Framework partial object. The book is using the linq to SQL object.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from creating another partial definition for your class as well as having the EF generated one.  In this case you would have your generated file, Data.cs (your main implementation) and Data.Validation.cs which is where you can define your OnValidate method signatures.